# update span using jquery find in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

I'm trying to update/refresh a specific  after data is returned from the server. 
I want to update span class="answer-final-score". I use class instead of ID because this HTML gets dynamically generated multiple times.

The jquery ($('.rating').on... gets executed once the user clicks on a star in the div class="answer-score"

```js
 $('.rating').on('rating.change', function (event, value, caption) {

            $(this).closest('.answer-container').find('.answer-score-final').text('aaa');   

// above works standalone but not in .done section of $.ajax call below
              

            .done(function (result) {                    
                var jsonReturn = JSON.parse(result);
                                     
                    $(this).closest('.answer-container').find('.answer-score-final').text(jsonReturn.score);                    
            })
```

```html
    <div class="answer-container">           
            <div class="answer-score">
                Score (<span class="answer-count">@Model.ElementAt(i).Count)</span><br /><br />
                <span class="answer-final-score">@(Math.Round((decimal)(Model.ElementAt(i).RatingScore)))</span>
            </div>

            <div class="answer-rateIt">
                <input data-id="@Model.ElementAt(i).OptionID" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="sm">
                <div class="hover">hover</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a JS expert so I don't know if this is best way, but this works.

```js
var answerScoreFinal = $(this).closest('.answer-container').find('.answer-score-final');   

// had to assign span object to a variable before making Ajax call, then 
// use answerScoreFinal.text('value') in the Ajax .done section.
              

          $.ajax({
                type: "post",             
                ...
            })
            .done(function (result) {                    
                var jsonReturn = JSON.parse(result);
                                     
                answerScoreFinal.text(jsonReturn.score);                    
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).closest('.answer-container').find('.answer-score > .answer-score-final').text('aaa');`

should work for you.  Instead of using find again, just use the original find and find one of its children.

Comment: Thanks Nic. My problem was that I referred to the wrong name (.answer-final-score < wrong). I fixed and it works in my test case - however, my real issue now is that it doesn't work in the $.ajax callback in the .done section. I edited my original question to reflect this. Thanks again.

Comment: Well I appreciate you changing the question so that my answer means nothing.

I would think you should probably ask a new question... but I don't make the rules

Comment: Also, from the anscestor div, I found that I can drill down straight using .find('.answer-score-final).text('aaa'). Again my prob before was wrong name ... doh !

Comment: Yeah, maybe SO can remove this answer but let my new question stand. Again I appreciate the original reply. Thanks.